Facing Container startup issue, when deploying Quart App in Azure APP service
I'm trying to deploy a Quart application to Azure App Service using a Docker container, but I'm running into an issue where the Docker container fails to start on port 8000 and disconnects.
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


Startup command Used : hypercorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app:app
Other configurations
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1
Deployment Type : Manual Deployment from VS Code
App service Plan : Basic - Linux

Error Faced: ERROR - Container for site has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

Expected Outcome:
Container needs to be started and need to also verify the startup command given was correct w.r.t to Quart

I'm deploying manually via VS Code, so I don't have a Dockerfile. Azure App Service handles Docker configurations automatically when deployment is done .

Based on the error message provided, the issue is related to the startup command.
I tried configuring the startup command that you've used, but I got the same  error. So, I changed the startup command to
gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app

I created a simple Quart application and successfully deployed it to Azure App Service without any issues.
This is requirements.txt:
quart
hypercon
gunicorn
uvicorn

app .py:
import  os
from  quart  import  Quart
app  =  Quart(__name__ 
@app.route('/')
async  def  hello():
return  'Hello, World!'
if  __name__  ==  '__main__':
port  =  int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)

I deployed the app successfully via visual studio code extension.
configure the below startup command to azure app service.

Here's the output after deployment:


Have tried this but still facing the same issue , could you please post the startup command from app azure service?

@kuppan I already gave the startup command from the Azure App Service at the beginning of my answer. If the issue persists, try creating a new App Service and deploy it again.

Thanks for the support @Sirra Sneha- After creating a new app service and deploying it got worked
